# Stuck in MySQL upgrade, but can't run old version to fix

Tags: mysql

Upgrading MySQL to version 8.2 is failing with the following error:

```
2024-01-16T22:04:31.970007Z 4 [System] [MY-013381] [Server] Server upgrade from '80100' to '80200' started.
2024-01-16T22:05:05.196376Z 4 [Warning] [MY-011836] [InnoDB] sdi_delete failed: Record Doesn't exist: tablespace_id: 1 Key: 1 4247748
2024-01-16T22:05:05.349958Z 4 [ERROR] [MY-013178] [Server] Execution of server-side SQL statement '-- Copyright (c) 2018, 2023, [blah blah blah] -- Alters the sys_config table for upgrades -- ALTER TABLE sys_config CHARACTER SET utf8mb4; ' failed with error code = 3958, error message = 'Failed to delete sdi for sys.sys_config in sys/sys_config due to missing record.'.
2024-01-16T22:05:05.352770Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013380] [Server] Failed to upgrade server.
2024-01-16T22:05:05.352787Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
```

`mysqld_safe` keeps trying in a continuous loop.

I have seen many questions like that, and also the trouble-shooting guide in the MySQL documentation, that to fix this, I must go back and use the previous version of MySQL to tidy things up. However, when I try to run the old version, I get:

```
2024-01-16T22:11:18.042211Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-014061] [InnoDB] Invalid MySQL server downgrade: Cannot downgrade from 80200 to 80035. Downgrade is only permitted between patch releases.
```

So it seems that the failed upgrade did not fully roll back to the previous state -- some part of the dat thinks it's at version 80200 even though the upgrade did not complete.

Now I can't run ANY version of MySQL to clean up the tables. Is there

1. Another utility I can run that doesn't require mysqld to be running?
2. A way to manually modify the sys_config to allow the upgrade to proceed? Delete it maybe so MySQL can rebuild it?

Comment: Delete the database, import the dump you made before starting the upgrade. You do have backups, right?

Comment: I am using a package manager, and didn't even realize the update was happening. But yes, I have backups. However, even after deleting the entire database I'm having trouble, which I will add to this question after some more investigation.